# Filemaker - How to Sum IF based on portal criteria

Tags: filemaker

You will have to excuse me, as I am still quite a novice in regards to Filemaker.

I have through a lot of google search's built a database that we use to record all the details related to livestock we have on feed in feedyards.

We enter invoice details into a separate "Financials" Table. The invoices are all linked to a specific animal via "EID" (Electronic Identity) and contain a Cost Code (ie, Cost Code "B" represents Buying Fees, Cost Code "TI" represents Transport Into Facilities.)

The financial details pertaining to an individual animal then display in a portal on its Financial Tab.

What I would like to display is a summary of the portal details for an individual animal based on Cost Codes.

```
Cost Code   Total Value
B               x
TI              x
```

I have tried to place a calculation into the Financial's Table.

```
If(Cost Code  =  "B"; Total ; )
```

However it will some times display and other times no.

If I attempted

```
If(Cost Code  =  "TI"; Total ; )
```

It will not display at all.

I have included a screen shot below, showing the financials portal, and the fields the portal are based off.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to create summarized totals based on Financials::CostCode. This is built into FileMaker's List View, but doesn't come for free in FileMaker portals, unfortunately.

One way to do this would be to set up a series of costCodeTotal fields in your Animals table. Each of these fields could use SQL to get the total of related financials values aggregated by costCode. Using raw SQL (not recommended in FileMaker, but shown here for simplicity) your code for each of these fields would like something like:

```
ExecuteSQL ( List(
  SELECT sum(cost);
  FROM financials;
  WHERE costcode = <a cost code> AND animalID = ?
  );
"";""; <the animal id>
)
```

This assumes you have a relatively small and finite set of cost codes.

There are several others ways you could do this, but the advantage of this approach is that you don't need to establish custom relationships for each cost code type, which more traditional FileMaker methods typically require.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, however I am not familiar with SQL at all. I am very much a stockman first, however I have managed to resolve my issue. 

I have managed to get it to work using relationships, quiet fiddly and i doubt it's the most efficient manner however i get my result! 

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Filemaker has no SumIf() function. There are several other ways to summarize only selected related records. For example, you could use a filtered portal (of one row only), filtered by the expression:

```
Financials::Cost Code = "B"
```

and place the `Cost Code` field, along with a summary field defined (in the Financials table) as total of Value, in the portal.

This has the advantage of not requiring any additional relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, although I'm unsure why it's not working correctly. You need to create buckets fields to place the totals in. Your calcs look a bit off, however. I would have written something like this:

```
Case (
  Cost Code = "B" ; Total ;
                    0
)
```

Make sure that you've unchecked `Do not evaluate if all referenced fields are empty`. That *could* be a source of trouble.

If that still doesn't work try another calc that is functionally the same but uses different logic, such as

```
Total * ( Cost Code = "B" )
```

Once you have the buckets filling up correctly, you can use the `Sum` function to get sums of the related buckets.

```
total_b = Sum ( Financials::total_b )
```

As a general troubleshooting tip, try building the calcs a piece at a time. Start with `Total`, then move to `Case ( True ; Total ; 0 )` and finally to the final form. Make sure each step produces what you expect. Your screenshot shows you using FileMaker Pro. Access to FileMaker Pro Advanced's Data Viewer is a big help in these types of cases.